# Determine current iframe ID/name

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a case where a php page should be loaded in two different iframe, depending by some condition.
I need to get from inside the page which iframe is the current one ( get frame ID or name)
I try several jquery/javascript script without success,
Somebody should help me?

Comment: If you need a reference to the iframe containing the page, it's [frameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement) (when no cross-origin pages are involved in).

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to determine the iframe name from [tag:javascript]?  Or from php - as you mention "*I have .. a php page [which] should be loaded in two different iframes*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general (same origin) approach would be to:

1. Generate a [unique identifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and store it on the [`document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/document) inside the iframe
2. Access the parent document with [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)
3. [Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for all the iframes
4. Check each one for a [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) with a matching UUID
5. Get the ID or Name from the iframe which matches

---

This wouldn't work if you were dealing with cross-origin frames.

---

It would be easier to simply pass the information in the query string.

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/foo.php?id=xyz"></iframe>
```